# Python: Mock doesn't work inside celery task

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, mocking, celery

I want to use python `mock` library for testing that my Django application sends email.

Test code:

```
# tests.py
from django.test import TestCase

class MyTestCase(TestCase):

    @mock.patch('django.core.mail.mail_managers')
    def test_canceled_wo_claiming(self, mocked_mail_managers):
        client = Client()
        client.get('/')
        print(mocked_mail_managers.called)
        mocked_mail_managers.assert_called_with('Hi, managers!', 'Message Body')
```

**First example - without tasks**

```
# views.py
from django.views.generic import View
from django.core.mail import mail_managers

class MyView(View):

    def get(self, request):
        mail_managers('Hi, managers!', 'Message Body')
        return HttpResponse('Hello!')
```

**Second example - with tasks**

```
# views.py
from django.views.generic import View
from . import tasks

class MyView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        tasks.notify.apply_async()
        return HttpResponse('Hello!')


# tasks.py
from celery import shared_task
from django.core.mail import mail_managers

@shared_task
def notify():
    mail_managers('Hi, managers!', 'Message Body')
```

The first example works normal, second example fails, with `Not called` exception.

My settings:

```
# Celery
BROKEN_URL = 'memory://'
BROKER_BACKEND = 'memory'

CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER = True
CELERY_EAGER_PROPAGATES_EXCEPTIONS = True
TEST_RUNNER = 'djcelery.contrib.test_runner.CeleryTestSuiteRunner'
```

Is it possible to perform such integrated test or the only way to solve this problem is split test into two?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found a problem and it was pretty silly. [Described here](http://alexmarandon.com/articles/python_mock_gotchas/) and [Here](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/patch.html#where-to-patch):

> The basic principle is that you patch where an object is looked up, which is not necessarily the same place as where it is defined.

I need to change:

```
@mock.patch('django.core.mail.mail_managers')
```

with

```
@mock.patch('path.to.tasks.mail_managers')
```

Comment: And another bit - I called task with `task_name.delay(args)`, so I had to patch `task_caller_location.task_name.delay`, not just `task_caller_location.task_name`.

Answer (score 4):

Testing the behavior of asynchronous tasks directly from the code that uses them can be tricky. One reason is that the test *may* execute assertions even before the task actually runs, which will likely give you false positives. What I do in cases like this is to break the testing into two steps:

1. Mocking the task and testing that it is called when it has to be called and with the expected arguments.
2. Test the task as a standalone function and by executing it as a normal function, i.e. without the need of the celery server.

To illustrate, this could be like:

```
# views.py
from path.to.tasks import my_task


def my_view(requtest):
    # do stuff
    my_task.delay('foo', 'bar')
    return HttpResponse('whatever')


# test_my_task.py
from views import my_view
from path.to.tasks import my_task


class MyTest(TestCase):
    @mock.patch('path.to.tasks.my_task')
    def test_my_task_is_called(self, mocked_task):
        client = Client()
        client.get('/')
        my_task.assert_called_with('foo', 'bar')

    def test_my_task_works(self):
        my_task('foo', 'bar')  # note I don't use .delay(...), .apply_async(...), etc
        assert 'my task did what I expected it to do'
```

This way you can test that your implementing code behaves correctly in regards to your task and that the task behaves correctly once it's called as expected.

I hope it's useful! :)

Comment: Gerard, thanks for your writeup! Could not figure out the official docs, but your approach worked just fine!